# Grails domain class creation from database

Tags: grails-domain-class

I would like to create grails domain classes from an existing database, normally i was creating database from domain classes now i need to create it from an existing database schema. Please help me if there is any command available for that.

Comment: Hey...can anyone help me with any commands available for this. I need this badly, because i am switching to groovy and i need to create the domains from my existing database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm on the same problem and I've found [this Grails plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20120807170443/http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-db-reverse-engineer/docs/manual/guide/single.html). It works perfectly: it inspects the existent database and creates domain classes, all ready to go. Just follow the steps showed in the example and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called GRAG: http://grag.sourceforge.net

Perhaps this might help.

Comment: GRAG is not compatible with Grails 2.1; Any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

- add plugin (runtime ':db-reverse-engineer:3.0.0') in buildconfig.groovy
- Change Hibernate version from hibernate4:4.3.6.1 to hibernate:3.6.10.18
- Define package config in config.groovy to generate domain class grails.plugin.reveng.packageName="com.app.promotion"
- List the tables, you want to generate domain classes in config.groovy grails.plugin.reveng.includeTables=["promotion","event","promotionexecutionstrategy"]
- Define the shcema config in config.groovy grails.plugin.reveng.defaultSchema=”t0006”
- Then execute the command “grails -Dgrails.env=**development** db-reverse-engineer”. Here development is the environment in the datasource.
- After complete these steps we can see the domain classes in the package as we defined list items.