# Grails linking tables using pre-existing SQL join table

Tags: sql, grails, join, groovy

I've got three tables, scenarios, forms and a link table to connect the two, a form can belong to multiple scenarios, and a scenario can have multiple forms, the link table holds that relationship information...  How do I do this in Grails?  I can't alter the structure of the tables that exist... :/

The structure of the link table is simply:

```
form_id (matches PK of form table)
test_scenario_id (matches the PK on the test scenario table)
[order] (defines the order in which the forms should display)
```

Within plain old SQL I can just utilise a join as follows but have no idea how to translate that into Groovy speak: -

```
select lnk_scenario_form.test_scenario_id, dbo.lnk_scenario_form.[order], dbo.form.form_id
from dbo.form
JOIN lnk_scenario_form on form.form_id = lnk_scenario_form.form_id 
JOIN dbo.test_scenario on dbo.test_scenario.test_scenario_id = lnk_scenario_form.test_scenario_id
where lnk_scenario_form.test_scenario_id = SCENARIO ID
order by lnk_scenario_form.[order];
```

Here are the classes I have set up so far: -

```
class Form {


    static constraints = {
        formDesc(blank:false,maxSize:100)
        }

    static mapping = {
        table "form"
        version false
        columns{
            id column:"form_id"
            formDesc column:"description"
        }
    }

    String formDesc
}
```

and

```
package fartframework

class TestScenario {


    static constraints = {
        testscenariodesc(blank:false, maxSize:100, unique: true)
        browser(inList:["RND","FF","CH","IE"], blank:false)
        myrelease(blank:false, maxSize:10)
        system(blank:false, maxSize:50)
        subSystem(blank:false, maxSize:50)
    }

    static mapping = {
        table "test_scenario"
        version false
        columns{
            id column:"test_scenario_id"
            testscenariodesc column:"description"
            browser column:"browser"
            myrelease column:"release"
            system column:"system"
            subSystem column:"subSystem"
        }
    }

    String testscenariodesc
    String browser
    String myrelease
    String system
    String subSystem

    String toString (){
        "${testscenariodesc}"
    }

}
```

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454897/grails-domain-class-creation-from-database)

Comment: cheers I'll take a look, almost looks too good to be true! O.o